# Can I use a WebSocket protocol to send and receive data from Cloud Firestore using an ESP32S3 Using ESP-IDF C

Tags: c, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, websocket, esp32

Google is deprecating Cloud Iot, so not an option.
https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/release-notes

> Cloud IoT Core will be retired on August 16, 2023. After August 15, 2023, the >documentation for IoT Core will no longer be available.

I would like to use Firebase - Firestore for my backend. It takes all the hassles out of keeping a server up and running, scalability etc.

I managed to send data after login and authentication from an ESP32S3 using ESP-IDF in C, (note not Arduino, and not C++), and would like to know if I can rather use a websocket for the communication, once the Authentication done, and if so, can you give me a code example or pointers.

With a websocket, I can send data to my own server hosted in Europe, in less than 400ms.
With Firestore, there is a large HTTP header, that includes the API key, and also the Auth Token, a large amount of data, quite a lot of handshaking going on over HTTPS, and eventually the data is sent. This takes more than 1400ms.

We are weighing items in a farming scenario, and need to weigh very frequently, and the 1400ms with fast internet is not acceptable.
So if I could still go with Firebase Authentication, and Firestore for data, I probably would be able to speed it up to even faster than 400ms if I could use a WebSocket client connection with the Firestore document store. I can use the Refresh Token if needed to refresh the Auth Token, and thus keep the socket connection up, every 3600s as required by Firebase, (that also takes quite long) but less of a hassle, as only once every say 55 minutes.
Any pointers, advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore supports multiple SDKs and wire protocols, but none of them work over web sockets. The closest you can get with Firestore would be its REST API, which is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest). It's not the easiest protocol to work with though, so I recommend using the API explorer that is built into the documentation to create examples for yourself.

Comment: Dear @FrankVanPuffelen. The closest SDK is C++, but no C SDK. I have implemented the REST cmds you refer to, and slow as mentioned. The open socket would have helped. Such a pity, as Firebase - Firestore has a lot to offer.